# How to apply javascript style inside iframe's child elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a javascript that changes the color of the h1 when it finds a string - "hours" inside the iframe:

```
var htmlString = $('#listas').contents().find('body').html();
var index = htmlString.indexOf("hours");
var h1Elements = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

if (index != -1)
    for(var i = 0; i < h1Elements.length; i++) {
   h1Elements[i].style.color = "red";
}

console.log('found')
```

I would like to apply this stylesheet with some child elements insted of h1:

```
iframe path:nth-child(3) {
 stroke: red; 
}
```

Apliyng it only to h1 does not seems hard but when it has to be applied into iframe's path's fourth child I get bit confused.

Is it possible to do it, and what is the correct way of doing this ?

Comment: This is the reason why you shouldn't set styles via JS, but set CSS class names. For example you could set a class name `.hour-heading` to each `h1` and use CSS to style child or sibling elements.

Comment: I have no access to CSS, it is a modification of another system that only alows JS. So you mean that is not possible ?

Comment: Everything is possible. It might get much more complicated…

Comment: Yeah just need to figure out the way.